# How do I pull a specific path string from a URL in Excel or Google Sheets with a formula?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I need to pull out the path from this URL in Excel/Google Sheets using a formula. Each URL below represents a separate cell/row:

https://www.example.com/florida-services?gclid=1234aIQoabcdIru_ay6Wu-wIV8YBaBR2QNQeabcdeAyAAEg123_0_xyz

https://www.example.com/south-dakota-services

https://www.example.com/illinois-services?fbclid=XYZabcd1234abcdIru_ay6Wu-wIV8YBaBR2QNQeabcdeAyAAEg123_0_123234234

How would I extract only the state name in the URL paths above? The formula would have to adapt to single word and multi word states.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "m\/(.+)-services")))
```

[image]